# ng-style not working/updating

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have this code in my `html` file. I want to display a square game board with `ng-style` updating the `background-color` as the program runs.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="col in board">
        <div class="column" ng-style="{'background-color': colour($parent.$index, $index)}" ng-repeat="row in col track by $index"></div>
</div>
```

Right now the `colour` function just returns a colour and the `board` is set up as such:

```
function setUp() {
    $scope.board=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
        $scope.board[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
            $scope.board[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
}

$scope.colour = function(col, row) {
    return '#e6e6e6';
}
```

nothing displays though when I try to run this. I was hoping it should display a square on the screen.

Comment: Can you include what your css looks like ? It seems that you are missing critical css attributes like width, height, float, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner div (the one which you are applying the ng-style to) has no content. So unless you add content or additionally style it to have a width and a height, it will not show up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the missing content inside the child div (second ng-repeat).

```js
function MyController($scope) {
    var BOARD_SIZE = 10;

    function setUp() {
        $scope.board = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
            $scope.board[i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
                $scope.board[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    $scope.colour = function (col, row) {
        return '#e6e6e6';
    }

    setUp();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyController">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="col in board">
        <div class="column" ng-style="{'background-color': colour($parent.$index, $index)}" ng-repeat="row in col track by $index">{{row}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you are not going to insert content, you should fix height and width (I used your `column` class)

```js
function MyController($scope) {
    var BOARD_SIZE = 10;

    function setUp() {
        $scope.board = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
            $scope.board[i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
                $scope.board[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    $scope.colour = function (col, row) {
        return '#e6e6e6';
    }

    setUp();

}
```

```css
.column {
    height: 20px;
    width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyController">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="col in board">
        <div class="column" ng-style="{'background-color': colour($parent.$index, $index)}" ng-repeat="row in col track by $index"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```